# AS3 - OOP - inheritance

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have the following inheritance structure:

```
var environment:AvEnvironment = new AvEnvironment(...); 
addChild(environment);    
environment.addChild(new Terrain());
environment.addChild(new Player());
```

I am trying to access a public property from AvEniroments class through the Player class, however I'm getting an undefined property error (#119). I've tried the following:

```
this.x = AvEnvironment.xs // public property in this class
this.x = parent.xs
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
var ev:AvEnvironment = AvEnvironment(parent);
this.x = ev.xs
```

but I get a TypeError. Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Whereabouts are you trying to access the parent in the Player class? The constructor?

Comment: What you're trying to do is very bad practice.  Can you give more information about what the end goal is, so that we can maybe point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try a different approuch. Dispatch a custom event from your player class. 
Let your enironment listen to the event. Within the listener set a property of that event.
When the event bubbles back to the player class he can get the value from the event. This way your player class can function without the AvEnvironment so it's a bit more OOP.

The code within your player class would be something like this:

```
function fetchEvXs() : Number
{
    var playerEvent:PlayerEvent = new PlayerEvent(PlayerEvent.REQUEST_XS);

    dispatchEvent(playerEvent);

    return playerEvent.xs;
}
```

your Environment class should have a listener like this:

```
player.addEventListener(PlayerEvent.REQUEST_XS, onRequestXs);

function onRequestXs(e:PlayerEvent) : void
{
    e.xs = 100;
}
```

Comment: While an event-based approach is definitely better, the child shouldn't know or need to know about properties on the parent.  If this is a value the child actually needs, it should expose it as a property on itself, and then the property should be set from outside (the parent or the factory code in the original post).